# File names on CSV with bad line errors

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm using the following code below to capture bad line errors when reading a csv through pandas. I'm having trouble getting the filename to be included. I tried using a list to append during the loop but resulted in every file showing an error instead of just the files with errors.

How can I get the filename included?

```
import os
import glob
import sys
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

UnzipFilePoint = Path(str(os.getcwd()) + '/Unzipped/')

def FindBadLines(zipPath):
    mydict = {}
    mylist = []
    old_stderr = sys.stderr
    result = StringIO()
    sys.stderr = result
    x = ''
    for f in glob.glob(zipPath):
        df = pd.read_csv(f, dtype=str,encoding = "ISO-8859-1", error_bad_lines=False)
        result_string = result.getvalue()
        f_name = os.path.basename(f)
    if len(result_string) > 1 :
        with open('bad_lines.txt', 'w') as bad_lines:
            for line in result_string.split(r'\n'):
                if len(line)> 5:
                    bad_lines.write(line.replace('\n','').replace('b','').replace("'",''))
                    bad_lines.write('\n')
    sys.stderr = old_stderr

zipPath = UnzipFilePoint / "*"
FindBadLines(str(zipPath))
```

Comment: what do you mean by bad lines? Is it just related to encodings of your file ? which you can't open or read the lines correctly? Would you post a bad line sample?

Comment: A bad line error would be : pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 10 fields in line 3, saw 12

Comment: I'm not sure about your case but, sometimes this error occurs when you want to open a csv file with default parameters (sep=",") and the line inside the csv file also contains comma. if you change delimiter (or sep) default (ex:";") maybe you can solve the problem.

Comment: That's the problem ,it is comma separate and some columns also contain commas. Trying to identify these.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the following working code :

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from pathlib import Path

UnzipFilePoint = Path(str(os.getcwd()) + '/Unzipped/')

def FindBadLines(zipPath):
    mylist = [] 
    for f in glob.glob(zipPath):
        f_name = os.path.basename(f)
        old_stderr = sys.stderr
        result = StringIO()
        sys.stderr = result        
        df = pd.read_csv(f, dtype=str,encoding = "ISO-8859-1", error_bad_lines=False ,warn_bad_lines=True)
        result_string = result.getvalue()
        sys.stderr = old_stderr
        if len(result_string) > 5 :  
            mylist.append([result_string,f_name ])
    mynewlist = []
    for i in mylist:
        i[0] = i[0].replace('b','').replace("'",'')        
        for x in  i[0].replace('\n','').split('\\n'):
            if len(x) > 1 : 
                mynewlist.append([x , i[1]])
    df = pd.DataFrame(mynewlist, columns = ['Error', 'File']) 
    print(df)


zipPath = UnzipFilePoint / "*"
FindBadLines(str(zipPath))
```